# Extra value 1 is appending with curl response

Tags: php, curl

From following two files I am getting output `(2000)1` but It should only `(2000)`

After getting value using curl extra 1 is appending, but why?

**balance.php**

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost/sms/app/user_balance.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=2&status=Y");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

**user_balance.php**

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("sms",$conn);
$user_id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_sms WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$rec = mysql_query($sql);
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($rec)) {
    $balance = $row["user_sms_balance"];
}
echo "(".$balance.")";
?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the PHP manual documentation for [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - Set value to TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

If you don't set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to `TRUE` , then the return value from `curl_exec()` will be the boolean value of the operation -- 1 or 0. To avoid it, you can set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `TRUE`, like below:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: I ran into this problem where I was trying to do a `json_decode()` from a `curl_exec` response; I kept getting `bool(true)` as my result. This option cleared that error and gave me the JSON I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that last response to this question was made back in 2017....

I have bashed my head around for past day and I finally got the results that I wanted. I had the same problem as the author of this question.

Maybe my solution will help others and if do help please vote it I would appreciate it.

So in my case I have build the plugin and using shortcode and cURL API get I am feeding API data into the shortcode output.

Anyway I had this working but also printing the Extra value , which is the true value from the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER.

I have solved this by passing ob_start() and ob_get_clean() inside of my shortcode function. This has cleaned and return the response that I wanted without the Extra value 1 appending at the end of my data response.

My shortcode function looks like this

```
function shortcode_init(){
  ob_start();
  include PLUGIN_URL . 'templates/shortcode.php';
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

As you can see I am including the additional php where my cURL API call is defined.
In case someone needs this..here you go.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = YOUR API END POINT URL HERE;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($err) {
  echo $err;
} else {
  // this returns the array from object
  // then we can easily iterate thought arrays and echo values that we need,
  $decoded = json_decode($response, true);
}
```